# Toolbar is overlapping the GridView of LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

The Toolbar is **overlapping** the GridView of Linear Layout, so more than 80% of the contents in the first row is being hidden by the Toolbar above it.

This happened after I added the `FloatingActionButton` in the `activity_main`. I tried to include the Toolbar in LinearLayout but it gave me a cast exception. If it's possible to include the Toolbar in LinearLayout, I'm fine with it. Also, I'm trying not to handle it statically by using `marginTop` or `paddingTop`.

Here is how it looks right now: [Screenshot](https://imagebin.ca/v/2wcY9uRdMuZs)

And here are the xml files:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/textlayout"
tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLUTIONS**

Apparently, there are many solutions for this: *(Credit goes to the answers and the comment discussions)*

**1.** include `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` `android:paddingTop="AnydpThatYouFurtherWantToAdjust"` in the LinearLayout of `content_main.xml` Credit: @VladimirJovanović

**2.** include `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
`android:paddingTop="AnydpThatYouFurtherWantToAdjust"` in the LinearLayout of `content_main.xml` Credit: @Burhanuddin Rashid

**3.** This is a long one, check @AbhayBohra's answer and then include `android:paddingTop="AnydpThatYouFurtherWantToAdjust"` in the LinearLayout of `content_main.xml` Credit: @Abhay Bohra and @Rahul Sharma

Comment: try to give margin top in gridview in content_main

Comment: @AbhayBohra It already solves the issue, but I don't want it static. The GridView should start from below the Toolbar.

Comment: Try adding paddingTop="20dp" to content_main LinearLayout

Comment: @Stallion Please read my above comment.

Comment: Add this android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" to your layout.
It will solve the problem. Your activity probably has  theme @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and that is the reason why content is going under Toolbar.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Yes there's a theme named what you mentioned. But I'm not explicitly calling that theme in my code. Also, in which xml file and layout should I add that line?

Comment: That theme is set for all your activities in Manifest (<application> part). Read a little bit about themes. It will help you a lot.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Yes, when I said that the NoActionBar is not explicitly called, it includes the Manifest file as well (Question Updated with Manifest.xml). Can you tell me in which xml file and layout should I add that line?

Comment: I am using this in a lots of my apps. android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
It will work without problems. Just add it to LinearLayout or GridView.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Yes, I'm actually using that. Thank You. Check the updated answers at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting appBarLayout and include statement in LinearLayout with vertical orientation

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `app:layout_behavior` to your content_main `LinearLayout` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
//This
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/textlayout"
tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @It's close, but still overlapping like 20%.

Comment: No, the numColumns should autofit the available width and should not be disoriented into just a vertical order. The overall UI design should remain the same.

Comment: What do you mean by It's close, but still overlapping like 20% @Mr.Robot

Comment: The extra line after `//This` is suffcient for the answer. It will work as a charm.

Comment: That's what I suggested in my first answer only

Comment: There are many answers to the extent of being correct. Also, check the correct solutions at the end of the question.

Comment: Padding and margin are not the real solution for this..its a patch work bro!! app:layout_behavior is meant to handle scroll event below apptoolbar..which was the reason your Grid layout was hiding under toolbar

Comment: Yes, but I still have to use Padding because the image in grid item still touches the margin of the toolbar according to your solution.

Comment: Using padding for proper view is right.But the problem you were trying to overcome using padding was not the suitable solution.I think my answer was right on spot for your question Anyway its your decision

Comment: I have to differ on that. It's correct, but the same thing could be achieved by writing the first solution that was suggested (at the end of my question). I still have to use padding irrespective of what I implement. Also, no current answers are foolproof, but if they are meeting the standards, I'm willing to change my decision.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"` to your `content_main.xml` LinearLayout.
The final code should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/textlayout"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="edu.ahduni.seas.gyapak.MainActivity">
```

Comment: And what exactly would it do?

Comment: PS: as @Abhay said add  include statement also  with the above mentioned answer and it should work like charm.

Comment: @Robot [THINGS YOU MAY NOT KNOW: TOOLS ATTRIBUTES](http://www.randomlytyping.com/blog/2015/6/17/things-you-may-not-know-about-tools-attributes)  Check the link and jump to Layout Pointers. It might help you to understand.

Comment: So I should change the Linear Layout to a parent coordinator layout in content_main?

Comment: Okay, it is working, but there the image is kind of touching the margin of the toolbar, how do I solve that?

Comment: Try to add top margin `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`  to the same linear layout of content_main.xml

Comment: No issues @Robo. The thing is your problem is solved anyhow. **High Five**

Comment: Check the solutions in the updated question (As no answer are absolutely correct). Due credits are given.